# Insert a DataTemplate into another DataTemplate programmatically

Tags: wpf, datatemplate

I want to create a customizable ListBox, in a sense that I want to choose at runtime, which items from the bound collection are shown. Something like:

```
<CustomizedListBox Format="[Name][Age]"/>
```

I have an ItemTemplateSelector, which can generate the contents nicely in a For loop. But now the story is, that I want to predefine the DataTemplates for the different parts of the list in XAML, and then combine them in ItemTemplateSelector. So my target is to have these definitions:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="Name">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name, StringFormat='Name: {0}'}"/>
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate x:Key="Age">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Age}" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

And then combine them programmatically.

My problem is that VisualTree for the data templates, generated in XAML, is Null - apparently, WPF "uses a different mechanism". And I can't use LoadContent - because I don't want to instantiate the templates just yet.

Is what I want at all possible?

Comment: I maybe don't understand your problem. Why don't you create a DataTemplate for your datatype, which contains two ContentControls referencing both your Name and Age DataTemplates?  It sounds that you are trying to work against the framework instead of using it.

Comment: Because this is supposed to be a dynamic user-controlled list. The "Format" property above is a dependency property, ending up in a TextBox.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/fc3104b6-c1b0-4ab0-a48f-adefdaeb0f57